# How to add jquery function in xsl (Date)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, date, xslt

I get the date as a string and need to display the Date in format like this: MM/DD/YYYY
If there is only a year I should add 01/01.
I also need to show in bold the albums which are above 2 years from today.
how do I do this? how do I add fuctions?
I can use JQUERY only and no JS.
Thanks.

here is my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
<style>
u { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#979994">
      <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Link</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Company</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Date</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Albums/Album">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Link"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Company"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Date" /></td>
      <td style="color:red;"><xsl:value-of select="Artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Albums1.xs"?>
<Albums>
    <Album>
        <Name>Empire Burlesque</Name>
        <Artist>Bob Dylan</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>Columbia</Company>
        <Date>19880610</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Hide your heart</Name>
        <Artist>Bonnie Tylor</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>CBS Records</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>19880509</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Greatest Hits</Name>
        <Artist>Dolly Parton</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>RCA</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>1982</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Still got the blues</Name>
        <Artist>Gary More</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>Virgin redords</Company>
        <Price>10.20</Price>
        <Date>1990</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Eros</Name>
        <Artist>Eros Ramazzotti</Artist>
        <Country>EU</Country>
        <Company>BMG</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>1997</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>25</Name>
        <Artist>Adele</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>XL Recordings</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>20151120</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>1000 Forms of Fear</Name>
        <Artist>Sia</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>RCA Records</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>20140704</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Rattle and Hum</Name>
        <Artist>U2</Artist>
        <Country>EU</Country>
        <Company>Island</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>19881010</Date>
    </Album>
</Albums>
```

Comment: jQuery *is* JS.

Comment: I was asked to do it with no plan js. and to use jQuery

Comment: You can do this purely in XSLT too, without recourse to javascript at all. Do you really need to use jquery here?

Comment: I think i need, because I need to bulid a seprate table for every contry, and order by the year of the album.

Comment: jQuery has no date methods so the formatting would be done using plain js or another library

Comment: can someone just show me how to add js to xsl?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is possible to call javascript functions in XSLT, it is very much processor dependent. However, you don't need javascript here at all. This simple formatting is something XSLT can handle directly.

Instead of doing this...

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="Date" /></td>
```

Do this....

```
  <td>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(Date) = 4">
        <xsl:text>01/01/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Date, 7, 2)" />
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Date, 5, 2)" />
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Date, 1, 4)" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </td>
```

Or maybe this...

```
  <td>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(Date) = 4">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('01/01/', Date)" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(Date, 7, 2), '/', substring(Date, 5, 2), '/', substring(Date, 1, 4))" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </td>
```

Comment: how do you suggest to implment the thing that I have to make a different table to every conuty? without dupplcating code..

Comment: You should read up on a technique called Muenchian Grouping first, as you will be grouping the albums by country. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Read it once. Then read it again.

Comment: I also need to show in bold the albums which are above 2 years from today. how do I get current date? I read that it is not easy to get current date, so I put current date as a veriable but it is not good programming...any idea? I edited my code

Comment: It is not considered good practise to change a question after it has been answered. Instead you should ask a whole new question. Thank you